# OneSignalにおいて、iOS、iPadのSafariのプッシュ通知で特定の条件で不具合が発生

Tags: ios, push-notification, safari

#### ■本題

OneSignalを使用し、
Webアプリケーションにプッシュ通知機能を導入しました。
iOS および iPadOS の Safari の場合
以下の特定の場合にのみ、
条件を満たさないと端末にプッシュ通知が届きません。

条件が揃うと、
蓄積されたプッシュ通知が
堰を切ったように一気に届きます。

解決方法を教えてください。

#### ■特定の場合

※フォアグラウンドの場合（admin.php以外のページの場合）
※バックグラウンド時（admin.php以外のページを表示してバックグラウンドにした場合）

#### ■条件

・ウィンドウバックでadmin.phpへページ遷移
・`<a>`,`<input type="submit">`でページ遷移

#### ■補足

admin.php のみが次のファイルを読み取っています。

- manifest.json
- https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js
  ※ process_push_tokens.js (OneSignal.init()、OneSignal.on()、トークンをデータベースに保存する処理を記載)

#### ■試したこと

admin.php 以外のページで、
上記の補足に記載されている 3 つのファイルを読みました
しかし、そうした場合
admin.phpを表示してもプッシュ通知が受信できなくなりました。

#### ■コード

manifest.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/web-manifest-combined.json",
    "name": "name",
    "short_name": "short_name",
    "display": "fullscreen"
  }
```

process_push_tokens.js

```
  window.OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function () {

    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "my_app_id",
      safari_web_id: "my_safari_web_id",
      welcomeNotification: [
        {
          title: "title",
          message: "message"
        }
      ],
      promptOptions: {
        slidedown: {
          prompts: [
            {
              type: "push",
              autoPrompt: false, // 自動表示しない
              text: {
                actionMessage: "xxx?",
                acceptButton: "許可する",
                cancelButton: "後で"
              },
              delay: {
                pageViews: 1,
                timeDelay: 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
    
    OneSignal.showSlidedownPrompt(); // 手動でダイアログを表示する
    
    
    OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) { // プッシュ通知を許可した際の処理
      if (isSubscribed) {
        OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
          insert_token(userId);
        });

      }
    });
  });
```

#### ■マルチポスト

- [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/fz1evecd163vbr)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259527/in-onesignal-there-is-a-problem-with-push-notifications-for-ios-and-ipad-safari)
- [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729888)

上記サイトでも同じような質問をしています。
理由は、かなりニッチな質問なので、
解決できる確率を少しでも上げたいからです。
解決致しましたら当質問にも報告致します。